# How to use gyroscope in Android

Tags: android, gyroscope

I need calculate yz angle in my application. I'm trying to use gyroscope for this, but it doesnt work. My phone even doesnt enter in functon onSensorChanged. Can you help me? This is my code

MainActivity:

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;

private float xy_angle;
private float xz_angle;
private float yz_angle;

private TextView yzPlane;


public  void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
{

}
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)
{
    xy_angle = sensorEvent.values[0];
    xz_angle = sensorEvent.values[1];
    yz_angle = sensorEvent.values[2];

    Log.i("Test", "Trying to change sensor" + String.valueOf(xy_angle));
    yzPlane.setText("Angle is: " + String.valueOf(yz_angle));
}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    yzPlane = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yzPlane);


}
```

I also have uses-feature in manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"/>
```

I have Sony Xperia M2 so it has a gyroscope. But ADB is giving me this error:

> 21681-21681/com.example.orientationsensor E/SensorManager﹕ sensor or listener is null

Comment: `I have Sony Xperia M2 so it has a gyroscope.` [citation needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A̶s̶ ̶i̶ ̶k̶n̶o̶w̶,̶ ̶X̶p̶e̶r̶i̶a̶ ̶M̶2̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶g̶y̶r̶o̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶  Try register for another sensor, f.e. accelerometer and see if `onSensorChanged` is called. Maybe bug...

Comment: Yes, thank you. I read 2 different sites , and one of this has information that m2 has gyroscope/ I tried with TYPE_ORIENTATION and it worked.